# Change values of a column conditionally using pipe() function

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use the `pipe function` of `dplyr` package to change values of a column conditionally. I used below approach -

```
library(dplyr)
> df = data.frame("Col1" = letters[1:6], "Col2" = 1:6)
> df %>% mutate(Col3 = ifelse(Col1 == "a", "aa", Col1))
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    a    1   aa
2    b    2    2
3    c    3    3
4    d    4    4
5    e    5    5
6    f    6    6
```

In above result, the first value of `Col3` is correctly assigned but not rest. Can someone please help me to understand the correct approach?

Comment: It's probably a factor. Convert to character and try again. Something like `df %>% mutate(Col3 = ifelse(Col1 == "a", "aa", as.character(Col1)))`

Comment: Not related to the issue at hand, but using a pipe operator isn't relevant to the problem. `mutate(df, Col = ifelse(Col1 == "a", "aa", Col1))` would have the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches :

Either use `as.character` in `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Col3 = ifelse(Col1 == "a", "aa", as.character(Col1)))
```

Or use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while constructing the dataframe.

```
df = data.frame("Col1" = letters[1:6], "Col2" = 1:6, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```